# pandas dataframe by boolean value, by index, and by integer

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean-expression

I have a similar problem to the one here [(dataframe by index and by integer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487932/pandas-dataframe-by-index-and-integer)

What I want is to get part of the DataFrame by a boolean indexing (easy) and look at a few values backward, say at the previous index and possibly a few more. Unfortunately, the suggested answer in the linked question with `get_loc` makes my code snippet choke (type error in the following snippet) before I can get the actual integer locations.

Taking the same example as in the answer in the other question, here is what I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2015,2,1)), data={'a':np.arange(32)})
df.index.get_loc(df.index[df['a'] == 1])
*** TypeError: Cannot convert input to TimeStamp
```

The previous answer used a string for `get_loc` where I'd just like to pass a plain index value (here a DateTime)

Comment: are you after `df.index.get_loc(df[df['a'] == 1].index[0])` assuming there is a single match

Comment: What does it mean to "look at a few values backward"? Does `df.loc[df['a'] == 1]` suffice?

Comment: @EdChum Your suggestion works for one hit, but that wouldn't scale if many values match and I want all their locations and not just the first one.

Comment: @unutbu If I needed just one, even `df[df['a'] == 1]` would be enough. What I meant by a few values back is I may want the value at the previous index, and possibly many more backwards. Unfortunately, I can't directly provide`get_loc`with the index I got from the boolean expression because it apparently needs a `string` instead.

Comment: you'd have to iteratively call `get_loc` with those index values to get the ordinal position if you're planning on looking at previous rows, I don't see how else you could do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a slice**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
index = pd.date_range(start=DT.datetime(2015,1,1), end=DT.datetime(2015,2,1))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(len(index))}, index=index)

mask = df['a'] == 1
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)[0]
lookback = 3
print(df.iloc[max(idx-lookback, 0):idx+1])
```

yields

```
             a
2015-01-08   7
2015-01-09   8
2015-01-10   9
2015-01-11  10
```

Note that if `idx-lookback` is negative, then the index refers to elements near the tail of `df`, just like with Python lists:

```
In [163]: df.iloc[-3:2]
Out[163]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []

In [164]: df.iloc[0:2]
Out[164]: 
            a
2015-01-01  0
2015-01-02  1
```

Thus, to grab elements relative to the head of `df`, use `max(idx-lookback, 0)`.

---

**Using a boolean mask**:

As you know, if you have a boolean array or boolean Series such as

```
mask = df['a'] == 10
```

you can select the corresponding rows with

```
df.loc[mask]
```

If you wish to select previous or succeeding rows shifted by a fixed amount, you could use `mask.shift` to shift the mask:

```
df.loc[mask.shift(-lookback).fillna(False)]
```

If you wish to select `lookback` preceeding rows, then you could expand the mask by unioning it with its shifts:

```
lookback = 3
for i in range(1, lookback):
    mask |= mask.shift(-i)
```

or, equivalently, use `cumsum`:

```
mask = (mask.shift(-lookback) - mask.shift(1)).cumsum().fillna(False).astype(bool)
```

The `for-loop` is clearer, but the cumsum expression is faster, particularly if `lookback` is large.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(start=DT.datetime(2015,1,1), end=DT.datetime(2015,2,1)), 
    data={'a':np.arange(32)})

mask = df['a'] == 10
lookback = 3
for i in range(1, lookback):
    mask |= mask.shift(-i)

# alternatively,
# mask = (mask.shift(-lookback) - mask.shift(1)).cumsum().fillna(False).astype(bool)

print(df.loc[mask])
```

yields

```
             a
2015-01-08   7
2015-01-09   8
2015-01-10   9
2015-01-11  10
```

Comment: Hi unutbu, what if I wanted to get all the rows starting from the row at `-lookback` to the current matching row? That's why my first approach was to look for a way to infer the current matching row number (say `m`) so that I could just index like this `df.ix[m-lookback:m]` or `df.iloc[m-lookback:m]` (I guess the second form is a bit faster as it's specialized for integer indexes). I'm going to play with your boolean index shifting approach.

Comment: Thanks for `np.flatnonzero`